# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'?

Tags: python, mysql

I use VSCODE run python connection mysql code, but get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'.

No install two module can't run code:
1.from flask_restful import Resource
2.from flask_restful import reqparse

How can I do? thank you!

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_restful import reqparse
from flask import jsonify

import json

DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_USER = "root"
DB_PASSWORD = ""
DB_SCHEMA = "flask_demo"


parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("name")
parser.add_argument("gender")
parser.add_argument("birth")
parser.add_argument("note")
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install flask_restful in your terminal using

```
pip install flask_restful
```

Answer (score 2):

install flsk-restful before running the code more reference https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

```
pip install flask-restful
```